# Show that $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\geq \sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{1}{k!}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{i}{n}\right)\right)$

Tags: inequality

I have to prove that $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\geq \sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{1}{k!}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{i}{n}\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

I think Left hand side is equal right hand side

since
\begin{align*}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\binom{n}{k}\dfrac{1}{n^k}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot k!}\cdot\dfrac{1}{n^k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{k!}\cdot\dfrac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-(k-1))}{n^k}
\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{k!}\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{2}{n}\right)\cdots\left(1-\dfrac{k-1}{n}\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{k!}\cdot\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}\left(1-\dfrac{i}{n}\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{k!}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\dfrac{i}{n}\right)\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: Very nicely done.