# Prove inequality using binomial theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, induction, binomial-theorem

I have this math question that I'm kind of stuck on.

> Use the binomial theorem to prove that for all integers $n\ge
>  2$:$$\left (1+\frac{1}{n}\right )^n < \sum_{j=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{j!}} <
>  2+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots +\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$$

I know applying the binomial theorem I get:$$\sum_{j=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{j}\left ( \frac{1}{n}\right )^{n-j}} < \sum_{j=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{j!}} <
 2+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots +\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$$
$$\implies \sum_{j=0}^{n}{\left ( \frac{\binom{n}{j}}{n^{n-j}}\right )} < \sum_{j=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{j!}} <
 2+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots +\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$$
$$\implies \sum_{j=0}^{n}{\left ( \frac{n!}{n^{n-j}\cdot j!\cdot (n-j)!} \right )} < \sum_{j=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{j!}} <
 2+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots +\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$$

I'm not really sure what to do from here... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

see:

[Show that $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\geq \sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{1}{k!}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{i}{n}\right)\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1570034/show-that-left1-frac1n-rightn-geq-sum-k-0n-left-frac1k-pro)
\begin{align*}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\binom{n}{k}\dfrac{1}{n^k}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot k!}\cdot\dfrac{1}{n^k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{k!}\cdot\dfrac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-(k-1))}{n^k}
\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{k!}\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{2}{n}\right)\cdots\left(1-\dfrac{k-1}{n}\right)\right)\\
&<\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k!}
\end{align*}

and
$$\dfrac{1}{k!}<\dfrac{1}{2^{k-1}},k\ge 2$$because 
$$k!=k(k-1)\cdots 2>2^{k-1},k\ge 2$$

Comment: How did you get $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{k!}\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{2}{n}\right)\cdots\left(1-\dfrac{k-1}{n}\right)\right)<\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k!}$

Comment: $(1-\dfrac{i}{n})<1,i=1,2,\cdots,k-1$

Comment: How does that explain it?

Comment: .. It is clear.

Comment: $-4 < 1$ and $-5 < 1$ but $-4*-5 > 1$ is my problem.

Comment: $(1-\dfrac{i}{n})>0!!$

Comment: do you know this ：if $0<a<1,0<b<1$,then $0<ab<1?$

Comment: Is $1-\dfrac{4}{1}$ greater than $0$?

Comment: 。。。。 do you konw $i<n?$